# How do i make css property run onload?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, onload, onload-event

I have a css that makes a button rotates and increases size. I want to know whether , only through CSS and HTML5, can i make that property run once the page is loaded completely or being loaded.

Example:
I have a rating list of 10 things which are displayed in a table with one entry in each row.
In front of each row is a number that displays the current position in the ranking of that particular item.

Now what i want to achieve is as the images and links are loaded of the list, the 10 buttons rotate and expand.

Also if this can't be achieve not only via CSS and HTML5, is there a way that Javascript can deal with it? A small example if possible would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, It's possible only using Javascript. 
These 10 buttons rotate and exapand when their respective row in the table loads, then for each , you can write & write the Javascript function onload event of the tr.
The sample could look something like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<head>
 <script>
function toDoForButton()
{
// You code goes here
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr onload=toDoForButton()>
<td>  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me if this is what you intended and it helps you.

--
Vinod